# Encapsulated flex-containers wrapping

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out how CSS-flex-containers work.
Currently I've got the following output:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luseP.jpg)

The big green ones are items in flex-container and the white tiles are items of a flex container in the other flex-container. But I want the items, to be arranged a little bit like the following:

[desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nSBM.png)

The following is my CSS. Can anyobody help me? It would be also enough, if me subitems (white ones) are arranged in a row and wrapped to a new row, if there are to many items in a row. But it doesn't work...

```
.container{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

}

.child{
    background-color: #496339;

```
margin: 5px;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
flex-grow: 1;
```

}

```
.childcontainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.childchild{
    max-width: 250px;
    background-color: lavender;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Added HTML-Structure:

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="child" *ngFor="let project of arrObject?.projects;">
    <div class="projectheader">[P] {{project.name}}</div>
    <div class="childcontainer" *ngFor="let job of project.jobs">
      <div class="childchild">

        <div class="jobheader">[J] {{job.name}}</div>
        <div class="jobcontent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [css grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) looks like a better solution to your problem. nevertheless, showing also your html structure would help.

Comment: @jcal I added the HTML-Structure (ngFor is from angular, because I read my data out of a json-file). I think using a grid I have problems in cause of the different sizes of my tiles (I tried the angular material-gridlist before).

Comment: If you're learning, here are two sources of wisdom: [Flexbox Froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com) and [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: @SteeveDroz Yes I'm learning that thing based on CSS-tricks. And I did that froggy thing, but there weren't any finding that helped me with my problems of sub containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake on my own.

The ngFor of the inner-container is in on the container-declaration.
It must be on the child-declaration.